# Modified Bessel function with Infinite sum in R

Tags: r, sum, bessel-functions

I am trying to implement the following formula in R where r0, t, theta0 and alpha are constants. Also, I is a Modified Bessel function of the first kind. My issue, I suppose, is from the Sum term to the end of the formula. I set n = 150 given that the function converges to zero fast so there is no need to go beyond 150. I am using the "Bessel" package.

[Formula1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prr8B.png)

[Formula2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv4b0.png)

[Results to reproduce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A3FF.png)  first row  = t, second row = Defaultcorr in %

Here is what I have thus far. I can't seem to find my mistake. Defaultcorr should be 0.04 % when t = 1 (according to the image "Results to reproduce"). 
To obtain this result " m " should be equal to 6.234611709.

```
V1 = 5
V2 = 5
K1 = 1
K2 = 1
sigma1 = 0.3
sigma2 = 0.3
Z1 = log((V1/K1)/sigma1)
Z2 = log((V2/K2)/sigma2)
t = 1
rho = 0.4

#One firm default -> Firm #1 when lambda = mu
PD_asset1 = 2 * pnorm(-(Z1/sqrt(t)))
PD_asset1
PD_asset2 = 2 * pnorm(-(Z2/sqrt(t)))
PD_asset2

#Results assuming that lambda = mu

#Conditions for alpha, theta0, r0


if (rho < 0) {                        #alpha
  alpha = atan(-(sqrt(1-rho^2)) / rho)
} else {
  alpha = pi + atan(-(sqrt(1-rho^2)) / rho)
}

if (rho > 0) {                        #theta0
  theta0 = atan((Z2 * sqrt(1 - rho^2)) / (Z1 - (rho * Z2)))
} else {
  theta0 = pi + atan((Z2 * sqrt(1 - rho^2)) / (Z1 - (rho * Z2)))
}

r0 = (Z2 / sin(theta0))                 #r0



#Simplified function

h = function(n) {
  (sin((n * pi * theta0)/alpha)/n)
}

n = seq(1, 150, 2)

Bessel1 = (besselI(((r0^2)/(4*t)), (0.5*(((n*pi)/alpha) + 1)), FALSE))
Bessel2 = (besselI(((r0^2)/(4*t)), (0.5*(((n*pi)/alpha) - 1)), FALSE))


l = matrix(data = n, ncol = n)
m = apply((h(l)*(Bessel1 + Bessel2)), 2, FUN = sum) 


PD_asset1_or_asset2 = 1 - (((2 * r0)/(sqrt(2*pi*t))) * (exp(-(r0^2)/(4*t))) * m)
PD_asset1_or_asset2


Var_asset1 = PD_asset1 * (1 - PD_asset1)
Var_asset1

Var_asset2 = PD_asset2 * (1 - PD_asset2)
Var_asset2

PD_asset1_and_asset2 = PD_asset1 + PD_asset2 - PD_asset1_or_asset2
PD_asset1_and_asset2

Defaultcorr = (PD_asset1_and_asset2 - (PD_asset1 * PD_asset2)) / (sqrt(Var_asset1 * Var_asset2))
Defaultcorr
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: And why do you suspect there to be a mistake?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce certain results that are based on this function and I do not get the right answer. I did not include the rest of the problem given that it is easy and straightforward.

Comment: Where are the results you're trying to reproduce ? Without the background, how could we help ?

Comment: I have adjusted it. Here is everything I have.